# How to use TLS 1.2 with appengine/urlfetch from a Go AppEngine app

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, go

I'm writing a go appengine app, which needs to fetch a page from Stripe.

Basically I'm using [these instructions](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go#google-appengine) that come with the official Stripe API.  However, when I run this with `dev_appserver.py`, I get:

```
2016/08/14 12:03:15 Requesting POST api.stripe.com/v1/customers
2016/08/14 12:03:18 Error encountered from Stripe: {"type":"invalid_request_error","message":"Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.","request_id":"req_90O6reF1Mwi9yZ","status":401}
```

I found that Python AppEngine apps can specify the SSL library to use in my app.yaml (see [SSL support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support)). However, if I add a `libraries` section to my app.yaml file, I get:

```
$ (go_appengine/dev_appserver.py app)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "go_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 89, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "go_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 85, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 758, in start
    options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 831, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(config_path, app_id)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 424, in _parse_configuration
    config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 2191, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 227, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/Users/kchodorow/gitroot/tt/go_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 178, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: libraries entries are only supported by the "python27" runtime
  in "app/app.yaml", line 25, column 1
```

Which makes sense, because I'm not using Python.  I really need a way to set this for Go.

My app.yaml file looks like:

```
application: app-name
version: alpha-001
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
...
```

Changing `runtime` to `python27` gets rid of the library error, but obviously then my go code doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get TLS 1.2 enabled, both with the dev appserver and production?

Comment: Are you not able to create a Transport on appengine ? Like `tr := &http.Transport{ TLSClientConfig:    &tls.Config{...},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}` maybe in the flex environment ?

Comment: Unfortunately, AppEngine requires that you use its Transport, [urlfetch.Transport](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference#Transport) (AFAICT). There might be some way to override whatever this transport's [RoundTrip](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/urlfetch/urlfetch.go#L169) is doing, which is what I'm looking for advice on.

Comment: I think it can be done on the [flex environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/) - see [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/internal)

Comment: Aha!  Using your advice about Transports, I dug down into what the RoundTrip code was calling and eventually figured out that I could use a vanilla http.Client, I just needed to set `Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment` in the Transport. If you'd like to write up an an answer, happy to award you the bounty.

Comment: So you set Proxy:http.ProxyFromEnvironment in urlfetch.Transport ? It's already set in http.Transport as DefaultTransport.

Comment: According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/issue-requests) you shouldn't really have to do anything other than perhaps AllowInvalidServerCertificate.

Comment: Yeah, this is now working with just `&http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,},},}`, no need to mess with urlfetch. I have no idea why `http.Client` wasn't allowed originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Go net/http documentation:

> For control over proxies, TLS configuration, keep-alives, compression, and other settings, create a Transport:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig:    &tls.Config{...},
    DisableCompression: true,
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

From the [appengine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/issue-requests) it appears you can use the net/http package as usual with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https). Appengine runs JDK7 and it supports TLSv1.2 but the default protocol is TLSV1

So it first tries to make connection in v1 and if it doesnt support try the other protocols v1.1 and then v1.2

As far as I know you cannot pass {-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2} to GAE but you may be able to set it through code
{System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");}

Comment: I don't think I can from Go.  dev_appserver.py invokes a [python backend](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py), so I'm wondering how to set this in Python/Go, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should create and setup new transport that has TLS configuration and uses the AppEngine service. It can be done by replacing default dial function with one that is defined by AppEngine SDK (with context).

```
// NewClient sets up an HTTP/2 client for a certificate and context
func NewClient(ctx context.Context) (*http.Client, error) {
    config := &tls.Config{}
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: config,
        Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            // this uses the appengine service to create the actual client
            return socket.Dial(ctx, network, addr)
        },
    }
    return &http.Client{Transport: transport}, nil
}
```